# Created a gridview in a tablayout and try to update Gridview with a Intent service

Tags: android, android-tablayout, intentservice

I have created a Tabbed layout in a Activity. My Activity as following point for consideration 
1. Number of tabs depends on sorting type available for a Source object. There can be max three tabs i.e. Top, Latest and popular.
2. Each tab contains a GridView and it should be updated when IntentService gets data
3. User can choose the Source from toolbar
4. When new Source is selected, number of tabs should be according to new Source and GridView should also update accordingly

TabbedActivity

public class TabbedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

private List<Source> allSourceItem;

private Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabbed);

    context = this;

    // register broadcast
    IntentFilter statusIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(Asset.ARTICLE_BROADCAST_ACTION);
    TabbedActivity.ArticleStateReceiver mDownloadStateReceiver = new TabbedActivity.ArticleStateReceiver();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mDownloadStateReceiver, statusIntentFilter);

    // set toolbar
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // set tab layout
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

    // set the viewpager
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);

    // set up page listner to viewpager
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    startSetUp(getRecentDisplayedData());

}

public void startSetUp(Source src){

    int tabsCount = 3;

    setTitle(src.getName());
    tabsCount = getNumberOfTabs(src.getSortByAvailableTop(),src.getSortByAvailableLatest(),src.getSortByAvailablePopular());

    setTabs(tabsCount);
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    mViewPager.setAdapter(new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabsCount,src));

}

// handle menus of activity
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tabbed, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SourcesActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("SOURCE_ACTIVITY_ACTION","TABBED");
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    if(id == R.id.change_src){
        //get all selected sources
        allSourceItem = Source.getAll();
        List<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < allSourceItem.size(); i++ ){
            listItems.add(allSourceItem.get(i).getName());
        }

        final CharSequence[] items = listItems.toArray(new CharSequence[listItems.size()]);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.chnage_news_source);
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                Source.updateRecentDisplayed(allSourceItem.get(item));
                restartActivity();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// for creatting tabs Fragments
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */

    private GridView mGridView;
    private ArticleAdapter mArticleAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Article> mGridData = new ArrayList<Article>();
    private TextView tv;

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabbed, container, false);
        tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.test_tv);
        tv.setText("Page counter :: "+getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        mGridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.article_grid);
        update(mGridData);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void update(ArrayList<Article> data){
        mArticleAdapter = new ArticleAdapter(getContext(),R.layout.aricle_grid_element,data);
        mGridView.setAdapter(mArticleAdapter);
    }

}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    int tabsCount;
    Source src;
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int tabsCount, Source src) {
        super(fm);
        this.tabsCount = tabsCount;
        this.src = src;
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).

        if( position == 0){
            runArticleService(position+1);
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }else if (position == 1){
            runArticleService(position+1);
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }else if (position == 2){
            runArticleService(position+1);
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return tabsCount;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "SECTION 1";
            case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";
            case 2:
                return "SECTION 3";
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void runArticleService(int tabNumber){
        Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ArticleService.class);
        mServiceIntent.setData(Uri.parse(Asset.getSourceArticleURL(src.getUniqueId(),tabNumber)));
        startService(mServiceIntent);
    }
}

// broadcast receivers handle
private class ArticleStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private ArticleStateReceiver() {

    }
    // Called when the BroadcastReceiver gets an Intent it's registered to receive
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String response = intent.getStringExtra(Asset.ARTICLE_EXTENDED_DATA_TYPE);
        String sortType = intent.getStringExtra(Asset.ARTICLE_EXTENDED_DATA_SORT);

        if(sortType.equals("TOP")){
            SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = (SectionsPagerAdapter) mViewPager.getAdapter();
            PlaceholderFragment placeholderFragment = (PlaceholderFragment) sectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(0);
            placeholderFragment.update(Asset.getArticleObjectFromJSON(response.toString()));
        }else if(sortType.equals("LATEST")){
            SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = (SectionsPagerAdapter) mViewPager.getAdapter();
            PlaceholderFragment placeholderFragment = (PlaceholderFragment) sectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(1);
            placeholderFragment.update(Asset.getArticleObjectFromJSON(response.toString()));
        }else if(sortType.equals("POPULAR")){
            SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = (SectionsPagerAdapter) mViewPager.getAdapter();
            PlaceholderFragment placeholderFragment = (PlaceholderFragment) sectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(2);
            placeholderFragment.update(Asset.getArticleObjectFromJSON(response.toString()));
        }

    }
}

// Extra methods
private int getNumberOfTabs(boolean top, boolean latest, boolean popular ){
    if( top && latest && popular){
        return 3;
    }else if( top && latest && !popular ){
        return 2;
    }else if( top && !latest && !popular ){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
}

private void setTabs(int tabCount){
    tabLayout.removeAllTabs();
    if(tabCount == 3){
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_1_text)));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_2_text)));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_3_text)));
    }
    if(tabCount == 2){
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_1_text)));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_2_text)));
    }
    if(tabCount == 1){
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.tab_1_text)));
    }
}

private Source getRecentDisplayedData(){
    Source src = Source.getRecentDisplayed();
    if(src!=null){
        return src;
    }else{
        src = Source.getRandom();
        Source.updateRecentDisplayed(src);
        return Source.getRecentDisplayed();
    }
}

public void restartActivity(){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, TabbedActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    finish();
}

}

IntentService

public class ArticleService extends IntentService {

public String responseStr = null;
public String urlStr = null;

public ArticleService() {
    super("ArticleService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Uri url = intent.getData();
    urlStr = url.toString();
    responseStr = Asset.fetchSourceDataFromURL(urlStr);
    sendBroadcast();
}

protected void sendBroadcast(){
    Intent localIntent = new Intent(Asset.ARTICLE_BROADCAST_ACTION).putExtra(Asset.ARTICLE_EXTENDED_DATA_TYPE,responseStr);
    if(urlStr.toLowerCase().contains(Asset.SORT_TOP_URL.toLowerCase())){
      localIntent.putExtra(Asset.ARTICLE_EXTENDED_DATA_SORT,"TOP");
    }else if (urlStr.toLowerCase().contains(Asset.SORT_LATEST_URL.toLowerCase())){
        localIntent.putExtra(Asset.ARTICLE_EXTENDED_DATA_SORT,"LATEST");
    }else if (urlStr.toLowerCase().contains(Asset.SORT_POPULAR_URL.toLowerCase())){
        localIntent.putExtra(Asset.ARTICLE_EXTENDED_DATA_SORT,"POPULAR");
    }
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(localIntent);
}

}
```

Error that I am not able to understand

```
01-26 07:57:29.789 1494-1494/in.co.yogender.newsnick.newsnick E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: in.co.yogender.newsnick.newsnick, PID: 1494
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:232)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:181)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:166)
at in.co.yogender.newsnick.newsnick.Adapters.ArticleAdapter.<init>(ArticleAdapter.java:0)
at in.co.yogender.newsnick.newsnick.TabbedActivity$PlaceholderFragment.update(TabbedActivity.java:197)
at in.co.yogender.newsnick.newsnick.TabbedActivity$ArticleStateReceiver.onReceive(TabbedActivity.java:273)
at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show ArticleAdapter.java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you are updating GridView from IntentService where Context is null. Try to pull context from IntentService like below and let me know.

```
public void update(Context cont, ArrayList<Article> data){
    mArticleAdapter = new ArticleAdapter(cont, R.layout.aricle_grid_element,data);
    mGridView.setAdapter(mArticleAdapter);
}
```